# Angular 4 reinitialise OR reset component nested within ngFor loop

Tags: javascript, angular

Can I do something with the following *ngFor loop (shown below) to force the *shared-text-input-component* to reinitialise OR reset? The problem I am facing is the component values are not resetting to there defaults as the component isn't being destroyed or reinitialised when a new contact is added / removed. Initially thought it was because the native DOM input did not have a unique name but this was not the case. I'm aware I could add logic into the *shared-text-input-component* to do a manual reset but I want to avoid this preferably. The main reason being that I am working on other shared input components which share the same problem and resetting the components through the Angular framework is more elegant than listening for changes manually and acting on them.

```
.Contact(*ngFor="let contact of contacts; let i = index;trackBy:ContactsChanged")
    .ContactDetails.form
        shared-text-input-component.InputComponent([value]="contact.model.value")
```

(Using PUG templating)

Comment: The component should destroy itself when it leaves the DOM, if it doesn't then you probably have some bad coding there, do you have any hanging subscription inside your `shared-text-input-component` ? Can you provide the code for your component ?

Comment: `shared-text-input-component` is a dumb component and is only ever passed data through data attributes. Angular is being clever with the diff and using the same instance but with different @Input values, hence destroy or init not being called again. I'm reluctant to listen for changes and exploring an option where the component is reinitialised when the contacts array is updated (Contact removed or added)

Answer (score 0):

Now working. trackBy function was returning undefined